# Boardman Hyb 8.6 - how to raise one piece handlebar/stem?

Tags: handlebars, hybrid-bike, stem, size

My battered old bike recently needed replacing. I have just bought a  [Boardman Hyb 8.6](https://www.boardmanbikes.com/gb_en/products/2365-hyb-8.6-silver-2021.html)  I am 6ft with a 6ft arm span and 32-33” inside leg. I was in between sizes for most brands but generally advised towards a large sized frame, which seemed to match my experience with my previous bike.

The Boardman sizing seemed to differentiate quite a bit from other brands and generally all of a Boardman’s sizes had slightly higher geometry than their other branded equivalents.

I got a M sized frame which was recommended for 177-183cm, which doesn’t seem overly small. The issue is that I do courier work and it’s imperative to set up an upright position. The problem with this and the Boardman is that not only is the stem threadless, the handlebar and stem are one-piece, making it difficult to make higher.

Here is a link to the bike in question with pictures:

My question is, what would be the best way to raise the handlebars? I have seen those stem extender tools, would that work?

[image]
 Stock photo from https://road.cc/content/review/boardman-hyb-88-297867

Comment: In America, bicycle fit you. In Soviet Russia, or apparently in the modern UK, you fit bicycle.

Comment: @Criggie is it possible that stupid one piece stem would attach to a stem extender?

Comment: @WeiwenNg yes it should, but then it will be too short.   This moves a lot of load to one's lower back/lower torso which is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

The headset is specified as a 1.5-`1/18" - standard. This means you can replace the combined bars and stem with any bars/stem you like. It may detract from the look, but you could then get any setup that fitted, so is certainly the most flexible option.

A cheaper option may be a stem extender. You will have a minimum height gain (although it appears there are spacers, so you could remove the spacers and cut the steerer down if needed). If you avoid cutting the steerer, this is easy to try, and completely reversible in a few minutes. The only real problem you may come across is you will need to trim the extender to length to suit the integrated bars, so will have less flexibility to make adjustments compared to a traditional stem/handle bars.

Personally, I think I would bite the bullet and buy a cheap extender to try, play around with height by trimming it down. You may end up going through a couple as you get the height right. Before cutting the steerer I would look at stem/bars and a proper bike fit, then decide if I wanted to keep the integrated setup.